# Finding numpy array expression equivalent to MATLAB

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, numpy

I am finding equivalent numpy expression which is equivalent to MATLAB expression like this:

```
[1: (arr(foo) - 1), (arr(foo) + 1): K];
```

where foo and K is integer, and arr is ndarray.
I thought equivalent code is like this:

```
np.append(np.arange(0, arr[foo] - 1), np.arange((arr[foo]), K))
```

However, if K is 2 and arr.size is 2, these two expression is not identical.
I think this is because MATLAB expression [1:1] returns 1, but np.arange(1,1) returns empty array.

How can I express above MATLAB code to Python3 code in efficient way?

Comment: Use `concatenate` rather than `append`. And make sure the individual `aranges` are valid.

Comment: @hpaulj as a python learner, Q: why its concatenate better than append for this?

Comment: Look at the code for np.append.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, its a convenient concatenate... Why would I not use that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Octave session:

```
>> [1: (5-1), (5+1) : 10]
ans =
    1    2    3    4    6    7    8    9   10
```

In Ipython with numpy:

```
In [70]: np.r_[1:5, (5+1):(10+1)]
Out[70]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

`np.r_` is a class with indexing method that uses `np.arange` and `np.concatenate` as in:

```
In [71]: np.concatenate([np.arange(1,5), np.arange(5+1, 10+1)])
Out[71]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

There are various cover functions for `np.concatenate` that manipulate the inputs, such as by adding dimensions, or raveling, etc.

The one that behaves most like the MATLAB `[x y; z w]` is `np.block`, which can concatenate lists recursively.  Here, though, it's no different:

```
In [72]: np.block([np.arange(1,5), np.arange(5+1, 10+1)])
Out[72]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

And for completeness, a Python list version:

```
In [73]: list(range(1,5))+list(range(6,11))
Out[73]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I don't like `append` because it is misused so often.  It isn't a clone of the list append.  Without `axis` it ravels the first argument.  It's ok for adding a scalar to a 1d array once, and that's about it.